# Converting moment into luxon times and hours

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

How can i migrate this line into luxon from moment, the code sample is given below,

This code sample is in moment, and i want to do it in luxon.

```
  timezone: null,
   getIn: moment().hour(14).minute(0)
      .second(0)
      .millisecond(0),

   getOut: moment().add(2, 'days').hour(11).minute(0)
      .second(0)
      .millisecond(0),


   getIn: 
  moment(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(moment(getIn).toISOString(), { zone: home.timezone }).toJSDate()),

getOut: 
  moment(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(moment(getOut).toISOString(), { zone: home.timezone }).toJSDate()),
```

Comment: Which is your desired output? Do you need to calculate "today at 14:00" and "in 2 days at 11:00" using luxon? You can refer to [For Moment users](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/moment) section of the docs to get information on how luxon works compared to momentjs

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent for those would be:

Proven to produce the same results with this [Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-t7ohpq?file=index.ts) (look at console output in the right panel)

```js
///moment
getIn: moment().hour(14).minute(0)
      .second(0)
      .millisecond(0),

//luxon
getIn: DateTime.now().startOf('day').set({ hour: 14 })
```

```js
//moment
getOut: moment().add(2, 'days').hour(11).minute(0)
      .second(0)
      .millisecond(0)

//luxon
getOut: DateTime.now().startOf('day').plus({ days: 2 }).set({ hour: 11 })
```

Comment: Thank you very much i checked in the console yes its working @SvetoslavPetkov

Comment: But do i need to add like this, DateTime.now().startOf('day').plus({ days: 2 }).set({ hour: 11, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 }); @SvetoslavPetkov

Comment: I am also having problem to migrate this  getIn: 
  moment(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(moment(getIn).toISOString(), { zone: home.timezone }).toJSDate()), into luxon @SvetoslavPetkov

Comment: 1. You do not need to set minutes, seconds ana milliseconds to 0. `startOf('day')` already sets everything to 0.

2. What is the desired output of this getIn, getOut. I see you mix moment and luxon within same lines. You want to parse the result of the getIn and output it into different timezone ?

Comment: no actually i want to make this line by using full luxon i will remove the moment but what is the exact way i am confused? will this work like this, luxon.DateTime.fromISO((getIn).toISO(), { zone: home.timezone }.toJSDate()), luxon.DateTime.fromISO((getOut).toISO(), { zone: home.timezone }.toJSDate()), is this line correct @SvetoslavPetkov

Comment: Yes you are right @SvetoslavPetkov

Comment: I still do not get what the output would be in order to help you. Luxon has a set time zone, method `.setZone()`.

Comment: Hello @SvetoslavPetkov Can you help me in this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74098865/issue-with-converting-momentjs-into-luxonjs-typescript    as I am replacing from moment into luxon, this sample code in my project.